# Show SplashScreen Programmatically

Tags: java, splash-screen

I'm currently working on a Java Application and it's my first Java App. So I created a file `Splash.png` and placed it into the source folder `resources`of the application.

I already managed it to show the Splash image on startup, with the JVM param `-splash:resources/Splash.png`, but my question is;

**How can  I show this splash screen again, but programmatically?**

I need this functionality for the `About` menu item.

Comment: before Splash Screen there were JWindow or JDialog(undecorated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your great help.
I thought there isn't really any function which does this, so I just coded a JFrame, which I can show instead of the Splash screen on launch. For the case that someone could need the code also I just post it here:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class AboutWindow extends JFrame implements MouseListener {

    public AboutWindow() {
        // show splash screen image
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("resources/Splash.png");
        JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
        getContentPane().add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // setup window correct
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        setUndecorated(true);

        pack();

        // place it at the right position
        Dimension windowDimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

        int x = (windowDimension.width-getWidth())/2;
        int y = (windowDimension.height-getHeight())/3;

        setLocation(x, y);

        // add the mouse listener
        addMouseListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
        dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
        // do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
        // do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {
        // do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: May be it will be nice to add setType(Type.UTILITY) :)

Comment: setLocationRelativeTo(null) is a shortcut to place it at the right position

Answer (score 4):

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html) is an outstanding example on using splash screens programmatically

The -splash is also described there.

Comment: Maybe the link has changed, but as of now this article does actually **not** explain how to show a splash screen programmatically, only via the `-splash` argument or by using the manifest.

Answer (score 2):

Use `java.awt.SplashScreen` class.

BTW I did not know that JVM has this cool options '-splash'. So, thanks for information!

Answer (score 1):

> How can I show this splash screen again, but programmatically?

The AWT based [`SplashScreen`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/SplashScreen.html) API that functionality uses, offers the [`getImageURL()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/SplashScreen.html#getImageURL%28%29)  method that might be handy in that respect.  The `SplashScreen` instance needs to be obtained early in the `main()` before any GUI elements are visible on-screen.

When it comes time to display the image, there are a multitude of possibilities best suited to different tasks and ways of using the image.  One of the easiest ways to display it would be:

```
JLabel splashLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(splashURL));
```

Pop that in a dialog or window as mentioned by mKorbel to show it on-screen.  Normally for 'splash-like' images we would want to go with pure AWT, but this situation is a bit different in that the GUI is already on-screen, so Swing would presumably be loaded and ready.